# How to find the single highest value? How to show everything if there is a tie?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to have the output of the movie(s) that have the most awards. The problem I'm having is how do I show a single movie? I tried to make a `PIVOT` function, and use the `MAX()` function rather than the `COUNT()` function; however I am would only get the output of 1 with almost all of the rows. I would however like to use the `MAX()` function to do this. I also want to know how can I show all "Movies" if there would be a tie? From my information there isn't going to be any tie, however if there were to be one, I would like it if all of the information would be shown.

Expected output:

```
MOVIE                               Awards Won
----------------------------------- ----------
Saving Private Ryan                          6

 1 rows selected
```

Output with my query:

```
MOVIE                               Awards Won
----------------------------------- ----------
A Lonely Place to Die                        5
Act of Valor                                 0
Captain America: The First Avenger           2
Date Night                                   1
Drive Angry                                  0
Saving Private Ryan                          6
Taken                                        1

 7 rows selected
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM
( 
   SELECT MovieTitle AS "MOVIE",
          TBLAWARDRESULT.AWARDRESULTDESC AS "Result Type",
          TBLAWARDRESULT.AWARDRESULTID AS "Rating"

   FROM TBLMOVIE
   INNER JOIN TBLAWARDDETAIL 
           ON TBLMOVIE.MOVIEID = TBLAWARDDETAIL.MOVIEID 

   INNER JOIN TBLAWARDRESULT 
           ON TBLAWARDDETAIL.AWARDRESULTID = TBLAWARDRESULT.AWARDRESULTID

   ORDER BY Movietitle
)

PIVOT
(
  COUNT("Rating") FOR "Result Type"
  IN ('Won' AS "Awards Won")
)
ORDER BY Movie;
```

Tables:

[File1 (PasteBin)](http://pastebin.com/yCmYPtAC)

[File2 (PasteBin)](http://pastebin.com/etWUTC63)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RANK` function to order the results by award count descending, which would get you multiple rows in case of ties as well.

```
SELECT MOVIE,Awards_Won
FROM (
SELECT 
MovieTitle AS "MOVIE",
COUNT(TBLAWARDRESULT.AWARDRESULTID) AS Awards_Won,
RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(TBLAWARDRESULT.AWARDRESULTID) DESC) RNK
FROM TBLMOVIE
INNER JOIN TBLAWARDDETAIL ON TBLMOVIE.MOVIEID = TBLAWARDDETAIL.MOVIEID 
INNER JOIN TBLAWARDRESULT ON TBLAWARDDETAIL.AWARDRESULTID = TBLAWARDRESULT.AWARDRESULTID
WHERE TBLAWARDRESULT.AWARDRESULTDESC = 'Won'
) t
WHERE RNK = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use pivot.  Use window functions:

```
SELECT "MOVIE", AWARDS_WON
FROM (SELECT m.MovieTitle AS "MOVIE", COUNT(*) as AWARDS_WON,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY m.MovieTitle ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TBLMOVIE m INNER JOIN
           TBLAWARDDETAIL ad
           ON m.MOVIEID = ad.MOVIEID INNER JOIN
           TBLAWARDRESULT ar
           ON ad.AWARDRESULTID = ar.AWARDRESULTID
      WHERE ar.AWARDTYPE = 'Won'
      GROUP BY m.MovieTitle
     ) m
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your on Oracle 12c there is the slightly simpler option to `ROW_NUMBER` of using `FETCH`.

```
SELECT m.MovieTitle MOVIE, COUNT(1) AS "Awards Won"
FROM
  TBLMOVIE m
    INNER JOIN 
  TBLAWARDDETAIL ad ON m.MovieID = ad.MovieID 
    INNER JOIN 
  TBLAWARDRESULT ar ON ad.AwardResultID = ar.AwardResultID
WHERE ar.AwardResultDesc = 'Won'
GROUP BY m.MovieTitle
ORDER BY "Awards Won" DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```